# File Permissions only for HTML

Tags: php, html, file-permissions

What file permission number i should set to a folder/file, such that the file can be accessed only from HTML?

I mean, if i have *images/background.jpg*, HTML can display the result of `<img src="images/background.jpg">` but if someone try to access ***http://website.com/images/background.jpg*** or ***http://website.com/images/*** do not have to see what's there.

Sorry for my bad English, I hope you understand.

Thank you!

Comment: whats your webserver?

Comment: This is not possible, since from the server point of view there is no real difference between the subrequest triggered by the html page and a manually entered request to the same URL. The only option would be to analyse the "referred header", but that is trivial to spoof.